# Error when setting date parameter in report builder to date/time

Tags: powerbi, report, builder

When I set the date range to type date/time I get an error saying “Dax comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Date with values of type Text. Consider using the value or format function to convert one of the values.

I have tried using the Cdate and Format(,”mm-dd-yyyy”) functions but that did not work

It works when I’m not using a range parameter and just using equal to